# Change the default SFTP directory on the raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sftp, filezilla, winscp

I want to use client such as FileZilla or WinSCP to tranfert files to my RPI. This works at the moment but everytime I start the connection the default directory is always /home/pi/

Is it possible to change it to a different repository without changing the setting of the client WinSCP / FileZilla?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manual page for [`sftp-server`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sftp-server) mentiones switch `-d`:

> **-d start_directory**
>
> specifies an alternate starting directory for users.  The pathname may contain the following tokens that are expanded at runtime: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %d is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that user.  The default is to use the user's home directory.  This option is useful in conjunction with the sshd_config(5) ChrootDirectory option.

Go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add this option with appropriate path to `sftp-server` value for `Subsystem` option.

Answer (score 0):

Winscp use ctrl-o to save position to list,you can select it.